# Google Chrome crashes with EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION on Sierra

Tags: macos, imac, google-chrome, crash, performance

New iMac running Sierra 10.12.5. 3 days ago suddenly started freezing intermittently for 3-5 minutes at a time. Activity Monitor was showing CPU spikes that corresponded to the freezes. Console reported some push spawn incidents. I pasted code into Terminal to get system report. The output is too long to paste here, but I have pasted into pastebin. Shortly after that, the computer froze and crashed. Tried to shut down, but it froze on shut down so I had to turn it off.

Restarted in safe mode. Seemed okay, so I started up Chrome - which at once reported that it had not shut down properly and began to act very unstable, flickering and loading from bottom over and over. I quit Chrome, uninstalled it and downloaded it, then reinstalled. But on opening it, it repeated the same bizarre behaviour.

In the meantime, Console system log shows:

> Jun 11 03:58:44 iMac com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.watchdogd): >Service only ran for 0 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 10 seconds.
>   Jun 11 03:58:54 iMac Console[919]: BUG in libdispatch client: >kevent[EVFILT_MACHPORT] monitored resource vanished before the source >cancel handler was invoked
>   Jun 11 03:58:54 iMac com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.watchdogd[937]): >Service exited with abnormal code: 255
>   Jun 11 03:58:54 iMac com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.watchdogd): >Service only ran for 0 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 10 seconds.

And it was constantly repeating the same thing.

Crash log shows:

> Process:               Google Chrome [776]
>   Path:                  /Applications/Google >Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome
>   Identifier:            com.google.Chrome
>   Version:               58.0.3029.110 (3029.110)
>   Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
>   Parent Process:        ??? [1]
>   Responsible:           Google Chrome [776]
>   User ID:               501
>
> Date/Time:             2017-06-08 23:53:55.944 +0800
>   OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.12.5 (16F73)
>   Report Version:        12
>   Anonymous UUID:        B346C290-BA5B-BE25-2627-258EB9202EB0
>
> Sleep/Wake UUID:       09EEC28F-8E0C-41B3-8428-51BCC9E7DD6B
>
> Time Awake Since Boot: 70000 seconds
>   Time Since Wake:       13000 seconds
>
> System Integrity Protection: enabled
>
> Crashed Thread:        0  CrBrowserMain  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main->thread
>
> Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (SIGILL)
>   Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000001, 0x0000000000000000

There's more to the crash log, but it's too long to put here.

What is causing the freezing? How can I uninstall Chrome and put things right again?

---

Also deleted Chrome & Chrome folder in `Application Support/Google`. Before I can reinstall Chrome, Console is continuing to report pushing:

> respawn: Jun 11 10:29:55 iMac com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.quicklook[2749]): Endpoint has been activated through legacy launch(3) APIs. Please switch to XPC or bootstrap_check_in(): com.apple.quicklook Jun 11 10:29:57 iMac com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.watchdogd[2750]): Service exited with abnormal code: 255 Jun 11 10:29:57 iMac com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.watchdogd): Service only ran for 0 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 10 seconds.

Comment: Delete the Chrome app, then in `/Library/Application Support/Google` delete the Chrome folder. Reinstall the Chrome app. Report back.

Comment: That should be `~/Library/Application Support/Google`, i.e. the folder in your user directory.

Comment: Deleted Chrome & Chrome folder in Application Support/Google. Before I can reinstall Chrome, Console is continuing to report pushing respawn:

Jun 11 10:29:55 iMac com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.quicklook[2749]): Endpoint has been activated through legacy launch(3) APIs. Please switch to XPC or bootstrap_check_in(): com.apple.quicklook
Jun 11 10:29:57 iMac com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.watchdogd[2750]): Service exited with abnormal code: 255
Jun 11 10:29:57 iMac com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.watchdogd): Service only ran for 0 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 10 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a bug in the Google Chrome application itself. This probably is related to word predictions feature (e.g. when switching input method and then typing right away).

See the existing bug report [No support for Chinese Input Predictive Completions on Mac OS Sierra](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=710101). People reporting it are having very similar crash reports.

If you think the problem is related to something else, feel free to report a [new bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/list) against Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, crashing was happening due to chrome extensions. Uninstall extensions and restart chrome and check if it is still crashing.